# Android Studio: Creating default project based on Android JetPack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using latest version of Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1 Patch 2. I am trying to learn Jetpack compose for user interface.

Every project that I create using the studio is based on XML files user interface.

How can I create the project user interface based on jetpack compose ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Select the "Empty Activity" (with the compose icon) while creating the project.

[image]

Comment: There is no such option in it

Comment: It should be "Empty Activity" in Flamingo. Look at the answer. I updated it. Can you see that option?